# Why Service Worker stalls http/https requests to the server?

Tags: service-worker, nuxt.js

I am creating a website using `django` and `nuxtjs`. I have installed `service worker` to improve speed. When I unregister `service worker` in `inspect/Application` tab, timing of my website in `inspect/Network` tab looks like this:

[image: timing of a request to the server without service worker]

When I use `service worker` opening website at the first time is fine, But when I reload the page or open another page of the website, the request to the server is queued long time. The timing of my website looks like this:

[image: timing of a request to the server with service worker]

which is queued 1.91 seconds. [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/understanding-resource-timing) describes reasons of queuing a request and all of them is in browser control.

I installed `service worker` with [pwa module](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/) which has `workbox` in its dependencies. My `nuxt.config.js` file is here:

```
import pkg from './package'

import {modify_html} from './services/amp/hook';

export default {
    mode: 'universal',

    /*
    ** Headers of the page
    */
    head: {
    title: 'example',
    meta: [
        { charset: 'utf-8' },
        { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
        { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [
        { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
    },

    /*
    ** Customize the progress-bar color
    */
    loading: { color: '#fff' },

    /*
    ** Global CSS
    */
    css: [
        '~/static/css/base.css',
        '~/static/css/hooper.css',
        '~/static/css/font-awesome/css/all.min.css',
    ],

    /*
    ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
    */
    plugins: [
        { src: '~plugins/ga.js', ssr: false }
    ],

    /*
    ** Nuxt.js modules
    */
    modules: [
        // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
        '@nuxtjs/axios',
        // Doc: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/
        'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
        '@nuxtjs/pwa',
        '@nuxtjs/device',
    ],

    manifest:{
        "short_name": "example",
        "name": "example",
        "icons": [
            {
                "src": "/static/icon.png",
                "type": "image/png",
            },
        ],
        "start_url": "/",
        "background_color": "white",
        "display": "standalone",
        "scope": "/",
        "theme_color": "white"
    },

    workbox:{

    },


    /*
    ** Axios module configuration
    */
    axios: {
        // See https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#options
    },

    /*
    ** Build configuration
    */
    build: {
        /*
        ** You can extend webpack config here
        */
        extend(config, ctx) {
        }
    },

    hooks:{
        // This hook is called before generatic static html files for SPA mode
        'generate:page': (page) => {
            if(page.path.includes('/amp/')){
                page.html = modify_html(page.html)
            }
        },
        // This hook is called before rendering the html to the browser
        'render:route': (url, page, { req, res }) => {
            if(url.includes('/amp/')){
                page.html = modify_html(page.html)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix `service worker` to do not stall new requests?